# C# Chart Data Converting Error

Tags: c#, web, charts

I'm trying to create a chart with regards to data from sql server. But i'm getting converting errors no matter what i try.

```
using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            var q = from u in db.Sites
                    where u.SiteURL == result.SiteURL
                    select u;

            List<webpagespeedtest_flat.DataModel.Sites> l = new List<webpagespeedtest_flat.DataModel.Sites>();
            l= q.OrderByDescending(s => s.CheckDate).Take(10).ToList();
            webpagespeedtest_flat.DataModel.Sites[] z = l.ToArray();
           // for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
           // { 
            //System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Series[] x  = Convert.(z[j].CheckDate);
            //}
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Series series1 = this.Chart1.Series.Add(Convert.ToString(z[i].CheckDate));
                //Chart1.Series["Score"].Points.Add(Convert.ToDouble(z[i].PageSpeedScore));
                //Chart1.Series["Date"].Points[i].AxisLabel = Convert.ToString(z[i].CheckDate);
            }

          //  Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -70;



        }
```

Series series1 = this.Chart1.Series.Add(Convert.ToString(z[i].CheckDate)); In this line i get  "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Series' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series' " error. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: `Series` is ambiguous here. Try this `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = ...` or delete the `System.Windows.Forms.data....` namespace or reference from the project as it is web application (as you mentioned `web` tag).

Comment: This solved the problem. When when i run it, on the browser, i get this error. "
No http handler was found for request type 'GET' 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: No http handler was found for request type 'GET'

Source Error: 



[No relevant source lines]
 
"